# XSLT transformation copy node

Tags: xml, xslt, transformation

How do i just copy node without any of the child nodes during transformation

```
<xsl:apply-templates mode="copy" select="test" />
```

here in the above example i just want to copy test node(none of the child nodes of test should be selected in transformation??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a template like this:

```
<xsl:template match="test" mode="copy">
    <xsl:copy/>
</xsl:template>
```

---

To copy the attributes, use:

```
<xsl:template match="test" mode="copy">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: I tried this but it doesn't copy attributes of the node(I need attributes of the node test also)

Comment: @user3767641 See the addition to my answer.

Comment: Thank you so much michael, sorry for asking too many question i am just trying to learn xsl. After creating template and applying that template to the xml node is there a way of add my own child nodes within apply template node

Comment: @user3767641 You can add child nodes within the `xsl:copy` instruction in the template that processes the parent node. If you cannot make it work, post a new question with a [mcve].

Comment: @user3767641 "I am just trying to learn xsl." Well, this is a very inefficient way of learning it.  Get yourself a good book!